# If I have a function that should have conditional behavior, what's the best way to do it?

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, data-structures

Suppose I have a Neural Network. I can perform a handful of operations in it, like so:

```
def one_iteration(my_op, data, ...):
    for i in range(...):
        ...
        my_op(data)
        ...
```

Imagine that `for` loop is doing a bit more than just being a for loop, and it's how I iterate over a collection of objects. Now, if pass as `my_op` a `training` function, I'm set. But, if I want to pass a `evaluate` function as `my_op`, now I want to keep my intermediate results to know how I'm doing. So I would do:

```
def one_iteration(my_op, data, ...):
    results = []
    for i in range(...):
        ...
        result = my_op(data)
        results.append(result)
    return results
```

And I would have a list/array with the results for me to evaluate how this network performed over that iteration. Now, suppose I want `my_op` to be `validate`, and for that, I need even more intermediate information. I could maybe do something like this:

```
def one_iteration(my_op, data, is_validation, ...):
    results = []
    if is_validation:
        more_results = []
    for i in range(...):
        ...
        result, other_result = my_op(data)
        results.append(result)
        if is_validation:
            more_results.append(other_result)
    return results
```

But, it starts getting all sorts of messy at this point. I know I could implement a separate `train`, `evaluate` and `validate` method, and within each one, I could do what's needed, but the problem I see is that each method will be repeating the way it iterates over the object (in this case, the for loop), and so, if I change how I iterate, I have to change it in 3 different places. Is there a design pattern I'm missing here?

Comment: It would appear that keeping the functions separate would be cleaner. You mentioned that you might change how to iterate over the data. Are you considering nested loops? If not, that could be easily abstracted. Perhaps you could expand a bit more on what potential future changes you want to design for. Although in general it's also good to do the minimal that is necessary now and refactor when you actually need it.

Answer (score 0):

So pass two methods: one that is the meta-operation, which accepts the operation:

```
def one_iteration(meta_op, my_op, data, ...):
    for i in range(...):
        ...
        meta_op(my_op, data)
        ...
```

And let `meta_op` decide how to handle the results.